# Load all files in the app bundle containing a string in their filename into a NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray, nsbundle, file-manager

So I have a folder called "content" in my app's bundle . I would need to load all files, which contain a string, I provide (for example "dog"), in their filename into a NSMutableArray. How can I do this, if it even is possible?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: "containing a string in their filename"; Aren't filenames strings, so all filenames will contain a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *resultFiles = [NSMutableArray array];
NSFileManager *fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *files = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bundlePath error:&error];
[fm release];

if (!error) {
    for (NSString *filename in files) {
        NSRange range = [filename rangeOfString:@"dog"];
        if (!(range.location == NSNotFound && range.length == 0)) {
            // filename contains "dog"
            [resultFiles addObject:filename];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks, but you forgot that the files I want to search through are in a FOLDER called "content" in the MainBundle.... thanks a lot tho...